# Unable to return info on hosts in multiple clusters in PowerShell using PowerCLI

Tags: powershell, vmware, powercli

I have a PowerShell script which is used to return information for each Host on a user specified cluster.  The user provides the vCenter and cluster in as parameters and the script works as expected.

I am trying to modify this script so the user only needs to pass in the vCenter as a parameter and it would return information for all hosts on all clusters.

Here is the original script I have which works:

```
Param(
    $vc,
    $ClusterName
)

Add-PSSnapin VMware.VimAutomation.Core

Connect-VIServer $vc

$VMHosts = Get-Cluster $ClusterName | Get-VMHost  | ? { $_.ConnectionState -eq "Connected" } | Sort-Object -Property Name

foreach ($VMHost in $VMHosts) {

 Get-VMHostStorage -RescanAllHba -VMHost $VMHost | Out-Null
 $esx = Get-VMHost $VMHost
 foreach($hba in (Get-VMHostHba -VMHost $esx -Type "FibreChannel")){
     $target = ((Get-View $hba.VMhost).Config.StorageDevice.ScsiTopology.Adapter | where {$_.Adapter -eq $hba.Key}).Target
     $luns = Get-ScsiLun -Hba $hba  -LunType "disk"
     $nrPaths = ($target | %{$_.Lun.Count} | Measure-Object -Sum).Sum
     $deadPaths = $luns | Get-ScsiLunPath | Group-Object -Property state | ? { $_.Name -eq "Dead"}
     $hbaDevice = $hba.Device
     $targetCount = $target.Count
     $lunsCount = $luns.Count
     $deadPathCount = $deadPaths.Count

     "vmhost=$VMHost;hba=$hbaDevice;targets=$targetCount;devices=$lunsCount;paths=$nrPaths;deadpaths=$deadPathsCount|"

 }
}

Disconnect-VIServer -Confirm:$False
```

And here is my modified version:

```
Param(
    $vc
)

Add-PSSnapin VMware.VimAutomation.Core

Connect-VIServer $vc
$clusters = Get-Cluster

foreach ($cluster in $clusters) {

    $clusterName = $cluster.name
    $VMHosts = Get-Cluster $clusterName | Get-VMHost  | ? { $_.ConnectionState -eq "Connected" } | Sort-Object -Property Name


    foreach ($VMHost in $VMHosts) {


        Get-VMHostStorage -RescanAllHba -VMHost $VMHost | Out-Null
        $esx = Get-VMHost $VMHost

        foreach($hba in (Get-VMHostHba -VMHost $esx -Type "FibreChannel")){
            $target = ((Get-View $hba.VMhost).Config.StorageDevice.ScsiTopology.Adapter | where {$_.Adapter -eq $hba.Key}).Target
            $luns = Get-ScsiLun -Hba $hba  -LunType "disk"
            $nrPaths = ($target | %{$_.Lun.Count} | Measure-Object -Sum).Sum
            $deadPaths = $luns | Get-ScsiLunPath | Group-Object -Property state | ? { $_.Name -eq "Dead"}
            $hbaDevice = $hba.Device
            $targetCount = $target.Count
            $lunsCount = $luns.Count
            $deadPathCount = $deadPaths.Count
            "vmhost=$VMHost;hba=$hbaDevice;targets=$targetCount;devices=$lunsCount;paths=$nrPaths;deadpaths=$deadPathsCount|"
        }
    }
}



Disconnect-VIServer -Confirm:$False
```

The error that I am getting is:

```
Could not execute powershell command.
At \\xx\xxx\xxxx\scripts\vmwarePathCheckAllClusters.ps1:35 char:26
+         Get-VMHostStorage <<<<  -RescanAllHba -VMHost $VMHost | Out-Null
```

It seems that `$VMHost` is being return as null, but I can't work out why!

This is my first time using PowerCLI CommandLets and I am very new to PowerShell as well.  I'm sure that this is something very simple and would appreciate any help.  If you require anymore information I'll be more than happy to provide.
BUMP!

EDIT: Here is the additional error info:

```
+         Get-VMHostStorage <<<<  -RescanAllHba -VMHost $VMHost | Out-Null ---> VMware.VimAutomation.Sdk.Types.V1.ErrorHandling.VimException.VimException: 9/24/2014 5:58:57 AM Get-VMHostStorage       Value cannot be found for the mandatory parameter VMHost     ---> System.Management.Automation.ParameterBindingException: Value cannot be found for the mandatory parameter VMHost
```

Comment: Have you tried running your Powershell console with elevated privileges? It may not be able to get $VMHosts properly without that.

Comment: Yes, I originally wasn't and it returned an error which stated I needed elevated privileges. Thanks.

Comment: Any others ideas as to why this wouldn't work? I find it strange that the original script works fine. I was doing some testing and $VMHost returns the correct Hosts for the cluster!

Comment: Hmm...Unfortunately, I haven't explicitly worked with clusters (or have one to test), so I don't have any direct ideas.  Are you able to successfully get all your clusters to populate your `$clusters` variable? If so, when you use your first `foreach` loop, is `$cluster.name` properly populating `$ClusterName`?  Also, perhaps modifying your code to use one cluster as a test might shine some light on whether or not there's another underlying problem separate from your modified script.

Comment: Hey Kris thanks for getting back to me. Yes the `$cluster` and `$clusterName` variables are both populating correctly.
I tried your suggestion by modifying the code to accept just one cluster statically set. Changed `$clusters = Get-Cluster` to `$clusters = @("server_name")` and it has worked fine!
Unfortunately I'm still unable to work out why this is happening though.  Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tested running `Get-VMHostStorage` without `-RescanAllHBA`? Why do you think `$VMHost` is being returned as null? Maybe it finds the host, but nothing to rescan? Just a guess.

Not sure this could cause your problem, but you don't need to run `Get-Cluster` twice. Rather,

```
$VMHosts = $cluster | Get-VMHost  | ? <etc>
```

*edit* - For a given run of the script, how many times does the full error text appear? How many vmhosts were found in that run? Do you have a cluster without hosts? A host without storage? You could set `$vmhost = $null` or `$cluster = $null` if a value from one loop iteration seems to be corrupting the next iteration. (Sorry, there's gotta be a better way to phrase that... hopefully you catch my drift.) You could always put the offending line of code in a `[try]` block and handle the error with [catch](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847793.aspx).

*edit again* - apparently [this](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847821.aspx) fixed it for the host in maintenance mode: `if (!$VMHost) {continue}`

Comment: Hey @noam, thanks for your response.  I have tried both your suggestions above and unfortunately I'm still receiving same error.
The reason I think it has something to do with `$VMHost` is due to an additional part of the error returned which I forgot to post above.  I will add it into the original question now.

Comment: Thanks you @noam, that was it. It's working as expected now.
There was a one VM on one of the cluster in maintenance mode.
If your ever in Belfast, I owe ya a pint :)

Comment: Just seen you updated. I actually used your original answer to add `if(!$VMHost){continue}` which works fine for me.

Comment: oops - i'll edit the answer again to include that. thx for clarifying.